# Showing traffic brought to main site by subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, google-analytics-4

I have a `mainsite.com` and writing blogs on `blog.mainsite.com`, and using different **GA4** code for tracking of them. Users would click some links in my blogs to visit the mainsite. How can I know the amount of traffic brought to mainsite.com by blog.mainsite.com? Thank you so much for your help.

I understand it may not considered as referer traffic.but really have no idea how to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable way is using of utm tags for links between your sites.